# remove last character from dict value python

Tags: python, dictionary, symbols

I have got a dict:

```
base = [
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '100EUR'},
    {'num': 22, 'bet': '10EUR'},
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '210EUR'},
    {'num': 11, 'bet': '100EUR'},
    {'num': 8, 'bet': '50EUR'},
    {'num': 10, 'bet': '10EUR'},
    {'num': 8, 'bet': '30EUR'},
    {'num': 32, 'bet': '10EUR'}]
```

I am trying to remove last 3 symbols from all 'bet' values and make the result from str to int- so my base to become like this:

```
base = [
        {'num': 10, 'bet': 100},
        {'num': 22, 'bet': 10},
        {'num': 10, 'bet': 210},
        {'num': 11, 'bet': 100},
        {'num': 8, 'bet': 50},
        {'num': 10, 'bet': 10},
        {'num': 8, 'bet': 30},
        {'num': 32, 'bet': 10}]
```

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Also the code solution have to be in definition

Comment: No - i have to delete last 3 symbols, so I will me able to tirn it in int

Comment: That's exactly what you can do with `replace("EUR", "")`

Comment: Ok - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Really you have a *list* of dictionaries; you can directly change the values in them by iterating and then by-name

```py
for subdict in base:
    subdict["bet"] = int(subdict["bet"].replace("EUR", ""))
```

this is fragile *on purpose* to discover bad values in your list (raising `ValueError` for non-int keys if `.replace()` fails or you have some other structure); you can (for example) also extend this to other currencies by detecting a substring like `"USD"` `subdict["bet"]` before doing a conversion (though you would also want to convert the currency)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and slice the `bet` key and convert to `int`

```
base = [{'num': b['num'], 'bet': int(b['bet'][:-3])}
        for b in base]
print(base)
```

Comment: Starting from python 3.9 it's possible to use [`str.removesuffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) which is a bit more safe.

Answer (score 0):

Update the values in place by slicing the values and converting to `int`:

```
for d in base:
    d['bet'] = int(d['bet'][:-3])
```

Output:

```
[{'num': 10, 'bet': 100},
 {'num': 22, 'bet': 10},
 {'num': 10, 'bet': 210},
 {'num': 11, 'bet': 100},
 {'num': 8, 'bet': 50},
 {'num': 10, 'bet': 10},
 {'num': 8, 'bet': 30},
 {'num': 32, 'bet': 10}]
```